# How to use wstringstream and getline with wchar_t?

Tags: c++, stream, stdvector, getline, stringstream

I have a pipe-delimited string that I want to put into the vector named `result`. However, it won't compile on `getline`. If I remove the pipe-delimiter character in `getline`, then it compiles:

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
wstringstream ss(L"1,2,3|4,5,6|7,8,9|");
vector<wstring> result;
wstring substr;

while (ss.good())
    {
    getline(ss, substr, '|');  // <- this does not compile with wchar_t
    result.push_back(substr);
    }
```

How do I use `getline` with an incoming `wchar_t` string? I could do `WideCharToMultiByte` but that's a lot of processing if I can use `getline` with a `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not compile because [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) requires that the delimiter and the stream use the same character type. Your string stream `ss` uses `wchar_t`, but `'|'` is evaluated by the compiler as a `char`.

The solution is to use the appropriate [character literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal), like this:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    wstringstream ss(L"1,2,3|4,5,6|7,8,9|");
    wstring substr;
    while (ss.good())
    {
        getline(ss, substr, L'|'); 
        std::wcout << substr << std::endl;
    }
}
```